# How to print specific amount of elements of array per line?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to print 10 elements per line of the array, so output would look something like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
...etc
```

And here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int array[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) array[i] = rand() % 1000;
    sort(array, array + 1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000;){
        i += 10;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            cout << array[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I can't get it to work. For some reason it repeats all the numbers over and over.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)`  You start at 0 and print up to i in each iteration.  i gets bigger, 0 is still 0.

Comment: I would change the behaviour, just use one loop and if it can be dividable to 10(%10) then print a newline.

Comment: There are two things, how to patch you code and how to write what you want a little better. Your code has a simple patch (eg see my answer below) but I think most programmers would write this with a single loop and not nested loops as you have. There are several good examples of that also below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner loop only uses `j` in the argument list.  It needs to also consider `i` so that it can skip past the numbers it's already printed out

There is an easier way though.  Instead of doing nested loops, just print out a new line every 10 elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000;) {
  cout << array[i] << " ";
  if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here for a nice compact answer:

```
const int N = 10;
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    cout << array[i] << ((i+1) % N ? " " : "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));
  int array[1000];
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) array[i] = rand() % 1000;
  sort(array, array + 1000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000;i += 10){
   for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
     cout << array[i+j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a live version: http://ideone.com/76ZVp8

The changes I made from the original code was to fix the inner loop to loop 
from

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
```

to

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
```

The reason for this change is you do not want to loop from 0 to i at each iteration of the outer loop. That would create an increasing # of outputs for each iteration of the outer loop starting over at the beginning.

Since I made the first change to restrict j from 0 to 9 the next change followed to fix the index that is printed the output array index from

```
cout << array[j] << " ";
```

to

```
cout << array[i+j] << " ";
```

After that I created the ideone code and noticed the still wrong output. The first 10 members of the array were being skipped by the initial increment of 10 in the following code:

```
i += 10;
```

By moving this increment to the outer for loop the increment of 10 will happen after the inner loop and the newline which is what we want. So the new code for the outer for loop becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000;i += 10){
```

Comment: The output is kinda weird.. why are all the 0s and the weird numbers at the end?

Comment: I am trying to figure that out. The code also skipped the first 10 elements. I just fixed that.

Comment: This looks more like code than an answer. Maybe you should elaborate on what was wrong with the OP's code, the changes you've made, and why they should be adopted.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
const int N = 10;
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 )  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is [j] here?

Comment: I copied and pasted the code and did not see the typo. I will update my post. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to print 11 elements per line also... just tested.

Comment: Try again, I swapped two statements in the loop body.

Comment: I think that the more correct would be at first cout << array[i] << " "; and after it 
if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 )  cout << endl;

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the program to output 11 per line?

Comment: Ternary operator is your friend: `cout << array[i] << (i+1)%N?" ":"\n";`

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Yes the conditial operator even is better than the if statement.

Comment: You need to take the mod of N, not N+1. Your code prints 10 numbers on the first line, then 11 on  every subsequent line.

Comment: The code was already tested by user2699298 Only for i = 10, 20, and so on the new line is outputed, Thus you are wrong.

Comment: If the newline is at the beginning of the body: `ìf (i && !(i % N))` -- that means: if i is divisibly by N *except the first line*.

Comment: Perhaps you could test it again? replacing the array print with an i print gives end of line numbers, 9,20,31,42,53

Comment: I mean the code I showed in the comments: 
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 )  std::cout << std::endl;

I uodated my post that there will not be any questions.:)

Answer (score 3):

For a smallest change to your code, change this line:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
```

to:

> ```
> for(int j = i-10; j < i; j++){
> ```

and it should mostly work. To avoid other issues you would also want to change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000;){
        i += 10;
```

to

```
for (int i = 10; i < 1000; i+=10) {
```

Still, those the various other answers that use `i % 10` will tend to be better general approaches.

Comment: This is a great solution as well! Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the inner loop:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        cout << array[j] << " ";
    }
```

Try to read it again and see what it's doing, maybe by stepping through it with the debugger, and you should be able to figure out why it's printing the same numbers again and again, and also why your lines are becoming longer and longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

...

If ((j % 10) = 0)

// Add a newline

...

Answer (score 0):

add a newline will be a simple way to solve this problem.
Simple means explicit behavior for descripting the processing.